# How can I add a point to an sf object?

Tags: r, r-sf

I have an sf object that stores point data. But I am having trouble understanding how to add a point to this object.

I know how to create two points in separate objects:

```
# Create sfg objects with coordinates of Los Angeles and Amsterdam
la_sfg <- st_point(c(-118.2615805, 34.1168926))
amsterdam_sfg <- st_point(c(4.8979755, 52.3745403))
```

And I know how to combine these two objects into one geometry set:

```
# Create sfc object with multiple sfg objects
points_sfc <- st_sfc(la_sfg, amsterdam_sfg, crs = 4326)
points_sfc
```

And I know also how to add attributes to these points using a dataframe:

```
# Create a data frame of attributes for the two points
data <- data.frame(name = c("Los Angeles", "Amsterdam"),
                   language = c("English", "Dutch"),
   
                weather = c("sunny", "rainy/cold"))

# Make sf object from separate data frame and sfc objects
city_profiles <- st_sf(data, geometry = points_sfc)
```

Now let's say I have another point coordinate with the following information:

```
name = Toronto
language = English
Coordinates =   c(-79.450717,43.691589)
weather = hot
```

I'm having trouble figuring out how to create an sfg object and then add it to my pre-existing feature collection. For example, intuitively I feel like I'd do something like this:

```
# Create sfg object
toronto <- st_point(name = "toronto", language = "English",weather = "cold", geometry=c(-79.450717,43.691589))
```

and then use rbind to add this feature to city_profiles. However this is not the correct syntax and only returns errors.

Comment: you need to follow your process again of starting from an `sfg` (`st_point()`), then to `sfc`, then to `data`, and **then** `rbind` the new row of data

Comment: so you'll have something like `toronto <- sf::st_sf(data.frame(name = "toronto", language = "English",weather = "cold", geometry = st_sfc(st_point(c(-79.450717,43.691589)))))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As SymbolixAU said you have to go all `sf` steps from all points and then `rbind` the results. Or bind it first and then go all the `sf` steps with all points in the same data.frame. For example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(rnaturalearth)

world <- rnaturalearth::ne_countries(scale = "small",
                                     returnclass = "sf") 

la_ams <- data.frame(name = c("Los Angeles", "Amsterdam"), 
                     language = c("English", "Dutch"),
                     weather = c("sunny", "rainy/cold"), 
                     lon = c(-118.2615805, 4.8979755), 
                     lat = c(34.1168926, 52.3745403))

la_ams <- sf::st_as_sf(la_ams, 
                       coords = c("lon", "lat"),
                       crs = 4269) 

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = world,
          mapping = aes(geometry = geometry),
          fill = "white") +
  geom_sf(data = la_ams,
          aes(geometry = geometry),
          size = 3,
          color = "red") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Add another point:

```
toronto <- data.frame(name = c("toronto"), 
                     language = c("English"),
                     weather = c("cold"), 
                     lon = c(-79.450717), 
                     lat = c(43.691589))

toronto <- sf::st_as_sf(toronto, 
                       coords = c("lon", "lat"),
                       crs = 4269) 

cities <- rbind(la_ams, toronto)

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = world,
          mapping = aes(geometry = geometry),
          fill = "white") +
  geom_sf(data = cities,
          aes(geometry = geometry),
          size = 3,
          color = "red") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]